# Binding to current DataContext with Converter using x:Bind

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, xbind

I have the following converter:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
         Debug.WriteLine(value.GetType());             

         //The rest of the code             
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the XAML that attempts to use the converter:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind StickersCVS.View}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:StickerCategory">
            <TextBlock Foreground="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This gives me an NPE at `value.GetType()`, apparently the value passed in is `null`.

If I change the following part:

`<TextBlock Foreground="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>`

to

`<TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>`

Then it works. The `Debug` correctly outputs `StickerCategory` as the type of the value. Any reason why `x:Bind` passes `null` into the converter and how do I make it work with `x:Bind`? I'm trying to pass `DataContext` to my converter.

Comment: Note that the default mode for x:Bind is OneTime (Binding defaults to OneWay). Can this be the root cause? Maybe the value is really null at the first binding....

Comment: Nope, no dice :(, I tried specifying the bind mode:

`<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Action}" Foreground="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource MyConverter, Mode=OneWay}"/>`

Still NPE. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: are you really sure about that? It's very plausible that with or without `Mode=OneWay` it's going to be null first - but without it, it'll never change. So since you don't have a null check in your converter, your program probably never comes to the case that there actually _is_ a value present?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{x:Bind}` uses generated code to achieve its benefits and while using different `Path` in `{x:Bind}`, the generated code has some differences.

Here I use a simple sample for example. For the complete sample, please check at **[GitHub](https://github.com/Z-Jay/xBindWithConverter)**.

In the sample, I have a ViewModel like following:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyList = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item {Name="1",Number=1 },
            new Item {Name="2",Number=2 },
            new Item {Name="3",Number=3 }
        };
    }

    public List<Item> MyList { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name: {0}, Number {1}", this.Name, this.Number);
    }
}
```

When we use `{x:Bind Name, Converter={StaticResource ItemConvert}}` in ***MainPage.xaml***

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.MyList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Item">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource ItemConvert}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

It generates following code in ***MainPage.g.cs***

```
public void DataContextChangedHandler(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DataContextChangedEventArgs args)
{
     global::xBindWithConverter.Item data = args.NewValue as global::xBindWithConverter.Item;
     if (args.NewValue != null && data == null)
     {
        throw new global::System.ArgumentException("Incorrect type passed into template. Based on the x:DataType global::xBindWithConverter.Item was expected.");
     }
     this.SetDataRoot(data);
     this.Update();
}

// IDataTemplateExtension

public bool ProcessBinding(uint phase)
{
    throw new global::System.NotImplementedException();
}

public int ProcessBindings(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    int nextPhase = -1;
    switch(args.Phase)
    {
        case 0:
            nextPhase = -1;
            this.SetDataRoot(args.Item as global::xBindWithConverter.Item);
            if (!removedDataContextHandler)
            {
                removedDataContextHandler = true;
                ((global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock)args.ItemContainer.ContentTemplateRoot).DataContextChanged -= this.DataContextChangedHandler;
            }
            this.initialized = true;
            break;
    }
    this.Update_((global::xBindWithConverter.Item) args.Item, 1 << (int)args.Phase);
    return nextPhase;
}
...
public void Update()
{
    this.Update_(this.dataRoot, NOT_PHASED);
    this.initialized = true;
}
```

And

```
global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock element3 = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock)target;
MainPage_obj3_Bindings bindings = new MainPage_obj3_Bindings();
returnValue = bindings;
bindings.SetDataRoot((global::xBindWithConverter.Item) element3.DataContext);
bindings.SetConverterLookupRoot(this);
element3.DataContextChanged += bindings.DataContextChangedHandler;
global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate.SetExtensionInstance(element3, bindings);
```

When initializing the Page, `element3.DataContextChanged += bindings.DataContextChangedHandler;` will be executed firstly. After this, `DataContextChangedHandler` method will be called as `DataContextChanged` event is raised while initializing. And the `ProcessBindings` method will be executed to update list item container element with bound data.

In the `DataContextChangedHandler` method, it calls `this.Update();` method which calls `Update_(global::xBindWithConverter.Item obj, int phase)` method in the end. But when the `DataContextChangedHandler` method is called, it `args.NewValue` value is `null`, so the `obj` in `Update_(global::xBindWithConverter.Item obj, int phase)` method is also `null`.

And when using `{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource ItemConvert}}` in XAML, the generated code for `Update_(global::xBindWithConverter.Item obj, int phase)` is:

```
// Update methods for each path node used in binding steps.
private void Update_(global::xBindWithConverter.Item obj, int phase)
{
    if((phase & ((1 << 0) | NOT_PHASED )) != 0)
    {
        XamlBindingSetters.Set_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBlock_Text(this.obj3.Target as global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock, (global::System.String)this.LookupConverter("ItemConvert").Convert(obj, typeof(global::System.String), null, null), null);
    }
}
```

As the `obj` is `null`, so the `value` in your `Convert` is `null` and finally it throws a NPE at `value.GetType()`.

But if we use another `Path` in `{x:Bind}` like `{x:Bind Name, Converter={StaticResource ItemConvert}}`, the generated code for `Update_(global::xBindWithConverter.Item obj, int phase)` is different:

```
// Update methods for each path node used in binding steps.
private void Update_(global::xBindWithConverter.Item obj, int phase)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        if ((phase & (NOT_PHASED | (1 << 0))) != 0)
        {
            this.Update_Name(obj.Name, phase);
        }
    }
}
private void Update_Name(global::System.String obj, int phase)
{
    if((phase & ((1 << 0) | NOT_PHASED )) != 0)
    {
        XamlBindingSetters.Set_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBlock_Text(this.obj3.Target as global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock, (global::System.String)this.LookupConverter("ItemConvert").Convert(obj, typeof(global::System.String), null, null), null);
    }
}
```

It will determine whether the `obj` is `null`. So the `XamlBindingSetters.Set_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBlock_Text` method won't be called here and the `NullReferenceException` won't occur.

To solve the problem,  just like @Markus Hütter said, you can add a `null` check in your converter like:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value.GetType());
        return value.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("value is null");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a good idea to use x:bind with converter in general, the goal of using x:bing is to increase performance, while converter will dramatically affect code's performance. you can easily create a readonly field in your model, and when your data is changed, you can raise property changed event, and convert the number there.

For example,

```
[JsonIgnore]
    public double IsUnreadOpacity
    {
        get { return (IsUnread) ? 1 : 0; }
    }

public bool IsUnread
    {
        get { return _isUnread; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _isUnread)
                return;
            Set(ref _isUnread, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsUnreadOpacity));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

However, since version 1607 you can use functions with `x:Bind` and this opens up new opportunities: quick conversion without the added complexity of converters. See the [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/function-bindings)